# how can I display like result of query in phpmyadmin?

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

***Model***

```
$q2 = "SELECT a.id, name, price FROM product a inner join detail b 
on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN ('".$id."') and status = 1 ";
$result = $this->db->query($q2);
return $result->result_array();
```

where $id = 41001,41002

so, i try it into phpmyadmin. here's the result

***phpmyadmin***

```
SELECT a.id, name, priceFROM product a inner join detail b 
on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN (41001,41002) and status = 1
```

the result of that query are :

```
id     name        price
41001  Coca Cola   4500
41002  Pepsi       4500
```

***View***

```
<?php foreach($resultsearch as $r){?>
  <li class="span3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <?php echo $r['id']?>
      <?php echo $r['name']?><span><br/>
      <span>Rp. <?php echo number_format($r['price'],2,",",".")?></span><br/>
    </div>
  </li>       
 <?php $no++;}?>
```

but, only display

```
41001  Coca Cola   4500
```

how can I display like result of query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: can you give us echo this after query $this->db->last_query(); give us result

Comment: @MohitJain here's the result : ?
SELECT a.id, name, price FROM FROM product a inner join detail b 
on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN ('41001,41002') and status = 1

Comment: i think its problem with quotes check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try your query like this

```
$q2 = "SELECT a.id, name, price FROM product a inner join detail b 
on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN (".$id.") and status = 1 ";
$result = $this->db->query($q2);
return $result->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo $result->num_rows();
```

If the result is 2, then you have a problem in the controller, you must have something like this:

```
$this->load->view('myview', Array('resultsearch' => $this->MYMODEL->myquerymethod($id)));
```

Comment: $result->num_rows();  and the result is 1